# How to obtain a vaccinations certification in Italy valid abroad

Tags: usa, italy

I'm planning to move the States and I need to get some documentation regarding my vaccinations.

Where can I request that? At the city council ("comune") or at the ASL ("Azienda sanitaria locale" - local sanitary establishment)?

Is it possible to get it translated in english in order to use it abroad?

Thanks

Comment: Not posting as an answer because I don't know about Italy. But about translation - I think everywhere in the world one standard yellow booklet is used, containing some introduction in English, and all names of the vaccines are in Latin so there's no need to translate it. I use my one issued in Poland everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick search turns up [two](http://www.uslumbria1.gov.it/pagine/come-richiedere-il-certificato-delle-vaccinazioni) [results](http://www.lettera43.it/it/comefare/istruzioni-pratiche/2016/10/19/come-richiedere-libretto-vaccinazioni/5944/) suggesting you need to consult your ASL/USL office. As usual in Italy there may be some local peculiarities depending on the region you live in.

It also appears that the booklet released will be the standard yellow international version that is also in English, so no translation should be required. I have used a German version (with French and English translations of the standard fields) before in the US and it was accepted without ado.